# How to use built-in date formats with EPPlus

Tags: epplus

I need to display the first letter of the month for a date value in a cell. In Excel I can select the M format under date (see below). How can I programmatically set that format using EPPlus in C#?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number format to get the first letter of the month is `mmmmm` (five m's). You can set the format for cells using `ExcelRange.Style.Numberformat.Format`.

Example:

```
ws.Cells["A1"].Value = DateTime.Today;
ws.Cells["A1"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "mmmmm";
```

Comment: Thank you! Works like a champ. Follow on - teach a man to fish instead of just giving him a fish :) Where would a wayward developer discover the format strings for one of those built-in formats?

Comment: @BrianNoyes As far as I can tell, EPPlus doesn't include the built-in formats to select from so you have to define your own custom formats which can match those built-in ones. The format syntax is defined by Excel, so for example Microsoft lists the guidelines on this [page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-or-delete-a-custom-number-format-78f2a361-936b-4c03-8772-09fab54be7f4). You can also see the actual format of the built-in ones if you click on Custom category in your screenshot after selecting a built-in format.

Comment: "You can also see the actual format of the built-in ones if you click on Custom category in your screenshot after selecting a built-in format. " - Perfect, exactly what I was looking for, thanks again!!